# Required NSSlider method (sliderDidMove) declaration not found on Apple's Developer Documentation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsslider

Working on a tutorial with a NSSlider.

What I want: Moving the slider will show slider value in NSTextField.

Tutorial explains that following method will show slider value in text field:

```
- (IBAction)sliderDidMove:(id)sender {
    NSSlider *slider = sender;
    double value = [slider doubleValue];
    [sliderValueLabel setDoubleValue:value];    
}
```

Method does not work so I tried to find the method declaration on Apples developer website
but couldn't find it. From my understanding is the method: sliderDidMove a class method
from the class NSSlider so why I'm unable to find any documentation?

Comment: Where I was looking for the method: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When slider value changes, it sends `-[NSControl action]` to its `-[NSControl target]`. So in Interface Builder you need to Ctrl-drag from the slider to the object that has `sliderDidMove:` (that will probably be either App Delegate or File's Owner). The name is chosen by the tutorial's author, it can be anything else.

Alternatively, you can set it up programmatically:

```
[slider setTarget:self]; // assume the handler is [self sliderDidMove:]
[slider setAction:@selector(sliderDidMove:)];
```

Note also that this particular task is better solved with bindings: bind both slider's and label's value to a `double` property of some object, and Cocoa will keep them synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift` ...

```
 // Somewhere maybe in viewDidLoad ...
        slider.target = self
        slider.action = #selector(sliderDidMove)



// Later on..

func sliderDidMove(){
    print("The slider moved!")
}
```